# Oracle - Group By with "steps"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to following table:

```
|MY_VALUES|
|---------|
| 1       | 1' iteration
| 3       | 1' iteration   | 2' iteration
| 2       | 1' iteration   | 2' iteration   | 3' iteration
| 5       | 1' iteration   | 2' iteration   | 3' iteration
| 3       | 1' iteration   | 2' iteration   | 3' iteration
| 2       |                | 2' iteration   | 3' iteration
| 4       |                                 | 3' iteration
```

I need a query which output is the following:

```
MY_RESULTS
----------
14
15
16
```

The query is basically summing the first 5 rows for the first result, then it goes forward of one value and it sums the other 5 and so on...

Is there a way to do it with Oracle? I cannot find on the documentation anything for doing such work.

Comment: look up window function with LAG

Comment: Your table has a problem because there is no column which can be used to generate the current order of `MY_VALUES` which you have shown in a table above.

Comment: Are there column names for each iteration?

Comment: @xQbert no, I don't have columns for the iterations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as 5 adjacent rows, unless you have a column specifying the ordering.

You can then do this using window functions, assuming you have such a column:

```
select t.*, sum(my_values) over (order by id rows between 4 preceding and current row) as sum5
from t;
```

This does it for all rows.  If you want to remove the first 4 (and the "id" doesn't make that easy), there are various ways:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(my_values) over (order by id rows between 4 preceding and current row) as sum5,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum >= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table is a bit thin with only the one column, so you haven't really got anything to order by, but something like this:-

```
WITH MYVALUES AS (
SELECT 1 MYVALUE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4 FROM DUAL
)

SELECT 
MYVALUE, 
SUM (MYVALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY NULL ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 4 FOLLOWING) S
FROM MYVALUES
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table had a row number already, you could get the result you want by iterating over the table and for each row using a correlated subquery which sums the values from the current row to 4 rows in front of it.

Since you don't have a row number already, we need to include it.  But you don't even have a column which can be used to reproduce the order of data you showed us.  In my query below, I assume that your table has a column `id` which can be used to generate an order.  If you don't have such a column, I would recommend that you add it.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT MY_VALUES,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(t2.MY_VALUES) FROM cte t2
     WHERE t2.rn BETWEEN t1.rn AND t1.rn + 4) AS MY_RESULTS
FROM cte t1
WHERE t1.rn <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable) - 4
```